# Angular 4 Eager or lazy load - SharedModule not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm unable to make my DropSelectComponent shared component work in loadChildren Contact or Support module. It doesn't work either eager or lazy loading. The DropSelect Component is part of services module and loads fine in Protected Module - layoutcomponent. Please advise?

**Protected.routes.ts**

```
const protectedRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'protected',
        component: LayoutComponent, 
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children:[
          { path:'', redirectTo: 'contact', pathMatch:'full'},
          { path:'support',  loadChildren: () => SupportModule},
          { path:'contact', loadChildren: () => ContactModule},
          // { path:'support', loadChildren:'./support/support.module#SupportModule'},
          // { path:'contact', loadChildren:'./support/contact.module#ContactModule'},
        ]
      }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(protectedRoutes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class ProtectedRouteModule { }
```

**Protected.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [BasicModule,  ServicesModule, ProtectedRouteModule],
    exports: [],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    declarations: [
        LayoutComponent
      ],
    providers: [LayoutService],
})
export class ProtectedModule { }
```

**Support.module**

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { DashboardCardsComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard-cards.component';
import { DashboardTableComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard-table.component';
import { SupportRouteModule } from './support.routes';

@NgModule({
    imports: [SupportRouteModule],
    declarations: [
        DashboardComponent, DashboardCardsComponent, DashboardTableComponent
    ],
    exports: [],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    providers: [],
})
export class SupportModule { }
```

**Support routes**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path:'', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch:'full'},
  { 
    path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, children:[
      { path: '', component: DashboardCardsComponent},
      { path: 'table', component: DashboardTableComponent},
    ]
  }

];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class SupportRouteModule { }
```

Services Module

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, HttpModule, FormsModule, RouterModule, MyDatePickerModule],
    declarations: [LoaderComponent, PagerComponent, FullScreenDirective, DashPipe, CutPipe, SearchPipe, DropSelectComponent],
    exports: [CommonModule, HttpModule, FormsModule, RouterModule, LoaderComponent, PagerComponent,  DashPipe, CutPipe, SearchPipe, DropSelectComponent],
    providers: [LoaderService, SessionStorage, LocalStorage, ClockService, StorageService,
            {
            provide: HttpService,
            useFactory: HttpServiceFactory,
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router, LoaderService, StorageService]
          },
    ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class ServicesModule { }
```

Comment: where is your shared module can you post

Comment: ServicesModule is the one I want to share across with ProtectedModule and SupportModule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not imported it in your `support.module`. Do this and it should work:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [SupportRouteModule, ServicesModule], // Here
    declarations: [ ... ],
    exports: [],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    providers: [],
})
export class SupportModule { }
```

Comment: Yep, thanks it works when I import in ServicesModule and do eager loading in ProtectedRouteModule but not when lazy loading...

Comment: I'm now facing - ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'protectedRoutes'. Consider exporting the symbol (position 9:7 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol ProtectedRouteModule in /protected/protected.routes.ts